# Why is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n} ]=(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Why is $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n} \right]=(a,b)$? Isn't it $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, which implies the union is $[a,b]$?

I am more comfortable with $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n} \right)=(a,b)$, but not convinced by the union of infinite closed intervals.

So they are equal?

Comment: In which of the closed intervals is $a$ contained in the union you mention in the title?

Comment: By the way: please make the question bodies *self-contained*. The title is just a title: what would you think of a book whose title is the first sentence of the main text?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that if $x \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Gamma} A_{\alpha} \implies x \in A_{\beta}$ for some $\beta \in \Gamma$. Now consider $$S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}\left[a+\dfrac1n, b- \dfrac1n \right].$$
If $a \in S$, then $a \in \left[a+\dfrac1n, b- \dfrac1n \right]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which is incorrect. Hence, $a \notin S$ and similarly $b \notin S$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that no matter how big you take $n$, the interval $\left[a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right]$ does not include either $a$ or $b$. That is, for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have

$$a,b\notin\left[a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right]\;,$$

and if follows immediately from the definition of union that

$$a,b\notin\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left[a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right]\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

The notation of $\bigcup_1^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$ simply refers to the set of all elements which'll be contained in any given set $[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$ where $n$ remains finite. An alternative notation may be to state $\bigcup_{\mathbb{Z^+}}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$ where we recall that $\infty\notin\mathbb{Z}$.

If this response isn't satisfying, let's see if a more concrete explanation will do better.

---

Consider the countable intersection $\bigcap_1^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})$. For me, it intuitively makes sense that this countable intersection of sets will necessarily become $[a,b]$ for the sake of consistency with the definition of closedness.

Looking at the proposed countable union of sets which are of interest at the moment, i.e. $\bigcup_1^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$, the original poster's questions essentially boils down to why we cannot say such union cannot be equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$. To respond to this: if in fact such union did simplify down to $[a,b]$, then it necessarily must follow that $\bigcap_1^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})=(a,b)$ according to the same logic.