# open intervals as union and intersections of closed and half closed.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I want to know if the following intervals are equivalent.

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+ \frac{1}{n},b)$$
$$[a,b) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a- \frac{1}{n},b)$$
$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+ \frac{1}{n},b - \frac{1}{n}]$$

Comment: See also: [Why is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n} ]=(a,b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276739)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalence, since you don't have any statements that could be equivalent.

If you want to know whether the identities you've posted hold: Yes, they are all correct.

Comment: I edit the second one, i want to know if it still holds

Comment: Yes, is is still correct.