# Open intervals as union of closed intervals

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

In Shreeve, it is stated that:

> Since an open interval can be written as a sequence of closed intervals, $$(a,b)=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}\left[a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right]$$

How can this be true?

Comment: Does the union of intervals on the right contain $a$? Does it contain $b$?

Comment: Also, beside JVV's comment, does the union contain every $a<x<b$? Can you find a closed interval $[a+1/n,b+1/n]$ that contains an arbitrary $x$ in $(a,b)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n} ]=(a,b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276739/why-is-bigcup-n-1-infty-a-frac1n-b-frac1n-a-b)

Answer (score 1):

$x \in (a,b) \iff a<x<b \iff$ there is $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $a+1/n \le x \le b-1/n \iff x \in [a+1/n,b-1/n] \iff x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}[a+1/n,b-1/n].$